# Group by multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do analysis for a card based game. Therefore I've got battle logs. Each player has 8 cards in one deck. The winner of the battle can be determined by comparing the number of crowns earned in that battle.

Now I want to figure out what card (saved in slot1-8) has the highest winrate.
The challenge is that it doesn't matter if the card is in slot1 or slot8 and hence I don't have a clue how I could solve this with a query.

Here is a SQL Fiddle with demo data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2b76/4/0

Comment: Can you elaborate `what card (saved in slot1-8) has the highest winrate` with an example?

Comment: Sure, let's assume we want to calculate the win rate for the card with the id 88. I am only checking for won games where the card 88 has been used in one of the 8 slots (http://i.imgur.com/9cJZiLs.png). I will count the amount of won games. Then I divide it with the number of games where this card has been used but the player lost with it. If that wasn't clear enough I am happy to provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: It is still little confusing. I created a sample fiddle with 2 slots and 2 rows. Here card 1 appear twice in winning crowns. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2c4b/1  Will the expected output be same in this case? Also if you build on couple of more rows in the fiddle I gave and show what the expected output would be.